# Distance of point from boundary of open set

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $G$ be open set and $a\in G$. If $\partial G$ is not empty set, can we prove $$\operatorname{dist}(a,\partial G) = \sup \{r: B(a,r) \subset G\}?$$

Comment: Not without further assumptions.

Comment: @DanielFischer what will be counterexample?

Comment: Without further assumptions, you can show $d(a, \delta G) \geq \sup \{r \vert B(a, r) \subset G \}$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens ya I got it. B(a,r)⊂G hence δG⊂X-G⊂X-B(a,r). Hence for all g∈∂G d(a,g)>=r.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks. But how we will prove it is true in R or R^n. and can you suggest some extra axiom made to have equality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ with the usual metric, and let

$$G = (0,3),\quad a = 1.$$

Then

$$\sup \{ r : B(a,r) \subset G\} = 1 < 2 = \operatorname{dist}(a,\partial G).$$

We always have the inequality

$$\sup \{ r : B(a,r) \subset G\} \leqslant \operatorname{dist}(a,\partial G),$$

but in general, the inequality can be strict.

We have equality in spaces where all balls are connected: Then suppose

$$s = \sup \{ r : B(a,r) \subset G\} < +\infty.$$

For every $\rho > s$, we need to show $B(a,\rho) \cap \partial G \neq \varnothing$. By definition, $B(a,\rho) \not\subset G$. If $B(a,\rho)\cap \partial G$ were empty, then

$$B(a,\rho) = (B(a,\rho)\cap G) \cup (B(a,\rho)\setminus \overline{G})$$

would be a partition of the ball $B(a,\rho)$ into two nonempty open sets, contradicting the connectedness of the ball.

In particular, we have equality in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for all $n$ (with any of the usual metrics), since balls there are connected.

Comment: ya got it. Thanks but why it is true in R or R^n?

Comment: I just added a sufficient condition for equality to the answer. I don't think there is a manageable non-tautological condition that is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: One more question: Does in a metric space paces all balls are connected implies space is connected?

Comment: Yes, for any $a\in X$ we have $$X = \bigcup_{r = 1}^\infty B(a,r),$$ so $X$ is a union of a family of connected sets with nonempty intersection. Such unions are themselves connected.